# how to assign Object keys to a same property and create an array of objects with name and value pair-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
obj= {
  sside: "1",
  id: 222,
  env: "Windows",
  platform: "Windows33",
  model: "IE9"
}
```

Now I want to convert this above object into this:

```
obj2 = [{name: "sside", value:"1"},{name:"id", value:"222",name:"env",value:"Windows"}];
```

I'm able to get all the keys in the array:

```
var keysArray= Object.keys(obj);
```

But im not sure how can I assign "name" field to every key inside the keysArray

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I would say no, given that `{name:"id", value:"222",name:"env",value:"Windows"}` is not a valid object. Are you sure you didn't want `[{"name": "sside", "value": "1"},{"name": "id", "value": "222"},{"name": "env", "value": "Windows"}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const obj2 = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({name: key, value: obj[key]}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the object and get each key and value and push this into an array.

```js
obj = {
  sside: "1",
  id: 222,
  env: "Windows",
  platform: "Windows33",
  model: "IE9"
};

arr = [];


Object.keys(obj)
  .forEach(function splitObj(key) {
    arr.push({name: key, value: obj[key]})
  });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That's what `map` is for.